# Pythonic List Iteration

Tags: python, django, iteration

I've got a list of Django Querysets that I'd like to combine into a single Query. The standard way of merging two Querysets is to perform the operation: `newQ = Q1 | Q2`, and I'd like to perform that operation on all elements of my list to form a single Queryset object.

This is pretty straightforward to do using a for loop, eg:

```
for qs in qs_list:
    if final_qs not in locals():
        final_qs = qs
    else:
        final_qs = final_qs | qs
```

Given the wonders of python it feels as though there is probably an inbuilt function of some kind that will do this for you. However, I had a look through the `itertools` library and nothing jumped out as a way of simplifying this operation.

So my question is, is there a more pythonic way of performing the above operation?

Comment: The canonical Python way is already given in the Martijn answer, but this `final_qs not in locals()` trick (you probably meant quoted identifier `'final_qs'`) made me shudder. In case of empty `qs_list` that will leave you with unbound local `final_qs` with catastrophic consequences. Explicitly assigning before the loop "no value yet" value such as `None` is better. Starting with an operation identity element (empty `QuerySet`) and altogether avoiding conditions in loop body is the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that function is called [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).  Use it with [`operator.or_()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_):

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

final_qs = reduce(operator.or_, qs_list)
```

`reduce()` takes the first to values of `qs_list`, passes those to the first argument, `operator.or_`, effectively executing `qs_list[0] | qs_list[1]`. It then takes that result, plus the next value in `qs_list` and applies the first argument again, and so on until `qs_list` is done.

For `qs_list` with 4 elements, that comes down to:

```
or_(or_(or_(qs_list[0], qs_list[1]), qs_list[2]), qs_list[3])
```

or the equivalent of:

```
qs_list[0] | qs_list[1] | qs_list[2] | qs_list[3]
```

but reduce works for any length of `qs_list` > 0 (for a list of length 1 the first value is returned without applying the first argument).

Note that your use of `if final_qs not in locals()` is very unpythonic; don't ever do that. You could have written your loop with an initial `final_qs` from `qs_list[0]` instead:

```
final_qs = qs_list[0]
for qs in qs_list[1:]:
    final_qs |= qs
```